# prevent SQL injection in django forms

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, sql-injection, django-1.11

I use this for validation:

```
class MyValidationForm(forms.Form):
  title = forms.CharField()
  body = forms.Textarea()
  taxonomy = forms.IntegerField()
```

and  this is my class-based view:

```
class blog_createpost(dashboardBaseViews):

 template_name = "dashboardtems/blog_createpost.html"

 model = {}

 def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    form = MyValidationForm(request.POST)

    if not form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponse("not valid")


    new_data = post(title=request.POST['title'],
                    body=request.POST['body'],
                    description=request.POST['description'],
                    taxonomy=get_object_or_404(taxonomy, 
                       pk=request.POST['taxonomy']),
                    writer=request.user)
    new_data.save()
    return HttpResponse("done")
```

like you see i check my received request validation  in this line: `if not form.is_valid():` and its working on but when i add some `SQL-command` inside my form inputs. it does not preventing to insert the value inside database!..
means i have a field in database which contains some value like `select * from user where 1=1`!.
doesn't it cause sql-injection danger from user inputs?...

Comment: Django already protects you from SQL injection attacks. Yes, the *data* that looks like a SQL command is inserted into the database, that is the proper response to such data. A successful SQL injection attack would *execute* the SQL instead of inserting it as data.

Comment: Note, one of the points of using a model form is that you can just do `form.save()` to create your post object. In any case, you should always access `form.cleaned_data` rather than `request.POST`.

Comment: That's why we use frameworks like Django. There is no need to reinvent the wheel. The framework takes care not only of SQL injection, but also XSS, CSRF, form validation and much more. You should invest more time in reading the documentation and getting to know the tool.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have misunderstood what SQL injection *means*. Django has successfully protected you from such an attack, the string `"select * from user where 1=1"` is being treated as **data**, not as a command, and ended up as a value in the database.

A SQL injection attack *alters the SQL that is being executed by the database*. A successful attack tricks the database into executing data as commands instead. You'd not end up with `select * from user where 1=1` as a value, but instead you end up with the attacker getting access to all results from the `user` table.

A classic error is to not properly escape data, by constructing the SQL command as a string. Lets say the server uses the following query to look up data for the current user:

```sql
SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$user_id'
```

where `$user_id` comes from the request. Normally that'd be a login name, say

```
user_id = "zopatista"
```

so the query becomes

```sql
SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='zopatista'
```

If the server does not protect against SQL injection attacks, an attacker can replace `user_id` and *inject more SQL commands*:

```
user_id = "zopatista' OR 1=1 -- "
```

so after simply interpolating that string into the query, now the server will send the following SQL to the database:

```sql
SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='zopatista' OR 1=1 -- '
```

and suddenly the *meaning of the query command has changed* and the database will return **all rows** rather than just one row matching the login name.

The [classic XKCD joke on SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) goes a step further and injects SQL code that *deletes the whole table*, rather than try to get access to more information.

A server protecting against SQL injection will make sure that user-provided data is always *parameterised*, sending the data to the database driver separately from the query to make sure it can never be seen as part of the query.

As long as you use Django's models and querysets, you'll be protected from SQL injection attacks. You would only be at risk if you mixed [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) or [`RawSQL()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.RawSQL) with user data without using their parameter features.

Comment: tnx ...grate illustrating

Comment: Thanks for that explanation @Martijn Pieters. Currently I have injected SQL in my views because I don't understand how I can fetch the data otherwise from Django models. I need to pull out details based on joins between two database tables. Could you please give some headsup on how I can replace the SQL query with maybe some model based query?

Comment: @NSP: that's way, way too broad. Django's ORM protects you from injections, and supports joins just fine. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/

Comment: I have this `cur.execute('''select teacher.teacher_id,teacher_name,subject_name from teacher,subject,teaches where(teacher.teacher_id=teaches.teacher_id and subject.subject_id=teaches.subject_id)''')` How can I change this with Django ORM? I am new to django, and this aspect is pretty complex to understand. Could you please suggest.

Comment: @NSP: sorry, no, I'm not going to do that. Please follow the Django tutorials, they are quite helpful there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure Thanks for the link